# is it possible to make content-src in content-security-policy dynamic?

Tags: cordova, content-security-policy

I have a cordova/ionic/angularjs app. The data content is loaded from a host/port that the user selects at setup time. This can vary by both user organization and dev/qa/prod run environment.

How can I obtain the same effect as if `content-src` was defined after the user had entered host/port in the app's setup page? It appears from W3 specs that CSP does not allow content-src to be overwritten, leave alone it being dynamic. Is there an idiomatic way of doing this?

Thanks